# Laravel Eloquent Multiple whereHas with Where condition

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-10, laravel-relations

I have models `Term`, `Concept`, and `Expression`. I have pivot tables `concept_expression` and `concept_term`.

##### Schema

- `terms` table

  - `id`
  - `term`,
- `concepts` table

  - `id`
- `expressions` table

  - `id`
  - `expression_plural`

##### Relationships

- `Term` model

  - `concepts(): BelongsToMany`
  - `expressions(): HasManyThrough`
- `Concept` model

  - `terms(): BelongsToMany`
  - `expressions(): BelongsToMany`
- `Expression` model

  - `concepts(): BelongsToMany`
  - `terms(): HasManyThrough`

I want to find `Terms` of a certain `Expression` category, but first, a concept should be found, because a concept is linked to an expression.

In my `CategoryController`, I'm trying this with Eloquent:

```php
$terms = Term::whereHas('concepts')
    ->whereHas('expressions', function ($query) use ($expression_plural) {
        $query->where('expression_plural', 'materials');
    })
    ->take(16)
    ->toSql();
```

The query that is being made is as follows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   `terms`
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   `concepts`
                      INNER JOIN `concept_term`
                              ON `concepts`.`id` = `concept_term`.`concept_id`
               WHERE  `terms`.`id` = `concept_term`.`term_id`)
       AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   `expressions`
                          INNER JOIN `concepts`
                                  ON `concepts`.`id` =
                                     `expressions`.`concept_id`
                   WHERE  `terms`.`id` = `concepts`.`term_id`
                          AND `expression_plural` = 'materials')
LIMIT  16
```

But I'm getting this error message when I check the query in HeidiSQL:

> Unknown column 'concepts.term_id' in 'where clause'

To be honest, I'm becoming confused about the relationships. What are the steps to find only certain expressions of a term, when there is also a concept between them?

In my controller, I also tried, for example:

```php
$expression = Expression::where('expression_plural', $expression_plural)->first();
$concepts = $expression->concepts->take(10);
```

And in my view, I just looped the `$concepts` to find the `$terms`, but I just want `$terms` directly in my view without the need to loop `$concepts`.

Comment: Where do you have the relational columns on your tables? Also share the literal code you are writing on your models to define the relations please

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered, `Unknown column 'concepts.term_id' in 'where clause'` suggests that the `term_id` column is not present in the `concepts` table, and that's because of the way you are trying to use `HasManyThrough` in this context, which is not directly applicable.

The issue lies in the fact that `HasManyThrough` is designed to work with direct relationships between models, whereas your models have `BelongsToMany` relationships, causing the problem. Check the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) to find out how it works.

My recommendation is to use the package "[eloquent-has-many-deep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)" by staudenmeir, which provides a solution for scenarios like yours, allowing you to define more complex relationships.

By using `hasManyDeep` method from the package, you can define the complex relationship between models and get the desired results directly in your view without the need to loop through concepts.

If you choose not to use the "eloquent-has-many-deep" package or any other similar package, you would have to resort to alternative methods like raw queries or additional intermediate queries, which can be less elegant and more cumbersome to implement and maintain.

Comment: I added this to my Term-model `public function expressions()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeepFromRelations($this->concepts(), (new Concept())->expressions());
    }` and now I can do this in my controller: `$terms = Term::whereHas('expressions', function ($query) use ($expression_plural) {
            $query->where('expression_plural', $expression_plural);
        })->paginate(16);`. It seems to work, like I wanted. Is that they way to use this package, making a model function and then use whereHas with it?

Comment: That's right, very good. Glad to have helped.